# buy function is not working please help

Tags: solidity, remix

transact to FpsCrowdsale.buyTokens errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
function buyTokens() public payable {
require(publicBuyActivated == true);
address payable transaction_sender = msg.sender;
uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
_preValidatePurchase(transaction_sender, weiAmount);

// calculate token amount to be created
uint256 tokens = msg.value / _rate;

_processPurchase(transaction_sender, tokens);
emit TokensPurchased(transaction_sender, address(this), weiAmount, tokens);

if (firstBuyTime[transaction_sender] == 0) {
    firstBuyTime[transaction_sender] = block.timestamp;
}

//dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, __wallet, msg.value);

__wallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

}

Comment: How do you compile your contract?

Comment: Is `__wallet` a contract? Also maybe the problem is in `_preValidatePurchase` or `_processPurchase`?

Comment: i use remix compiler

Comment: __wallet is not the  contract no

Comment: Unless you provide more details it is gust guessing. What's `publicBuyActivated` value? What is `__wallet`? EOA, contract. What does `_processPurchase` do? Remix has a debugger where you can execute transaction step by step until the line that fail is determined.